# Specify custom name for asp-for (Need only the child property)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Let's say I have this code:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="CurrentThread.ThreadId" />
```

This will generate a hidden input with the name `CurrentThread_ThreadId`. However, I would like the name to be `"ThreadId"` only. Basically, would like to ignore any parent class and only wanting the name of the last property.

I can easily do:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="CurrentThread.ThreadId" name="ThreadId" />
```

However, I am losing intellisense.

I was just wondering if there is a something I can do to generate name `"ThreadId"` with Intellisense.

Comment: Why would you want to do that (and ensure model binding does NOT work as intended)?

Comment: On my view, I'm passing in ViewModel, however, on my Post, I'm just trying to bind CurrentThread class (Not the ViewModel).

Comment: First that sounds suspiciously like you have a data model in your view model (which is dreadful practice). And your use the `[Bind(Prefix = "CurrentThread")]` in any case. but if you really want to screw up model binding you can always use `name="nameof(CurrentThread.ThreadId)"

Comment: Would you be able to explain why this is a bad practice? This is a "Dashboard" sort of page. So, in this page, there are actually 3 forms. There is the man ViewModel, inside there is: CurrentThread, CurrentComment, AddNewItem. So basically, a user can add any of those 3 things from the Dasboard page. Let's say, they chose "AddNewItem" form. When posting, AddNewItem, I only wanted it to bind "AddNewItem" class, instead of the entire VM that has 3 other classes. Is this wrong way of doing this? P.S. nameof worked. If you want to submit a post, I can accept it.

Comment: Your post action should accept the same view model your get action sends. Anything else will be a constant source of problems.

Comment: You can only submit one form, so why generate all that extra html which will never be used (either redirect to the appropriate form, or use ajax to load just the from you need). Doing this means you will never get correct 2-way model binding (validation messages for example will not work, and returning the view if `ModelState` is invalid will be a problem). You should never change the `name` attribute (or `value` attribute) when using TagHelpers (or `HtmlHelper` methods) - they will always generate the correct html for model binding and validation

Answer (score 7):

You can extend the existing input tag helper to set a custom value for `name` attribute.

```
[HtmlTargetElement("input", TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag)]
public class MyTagHelper : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.InputTagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-short-name")]
    public bool IsShortName { set; get; }

    public MyTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator generator) : base(generator)
    {
    }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (IsShortName)
        {
            string nameAttrValue = (string)output.Attributes.Single(a => a.Name == "name").Value;
            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("name", nameAttrValue.Split('.').Last());
        }
        base.Process(context, output);
    }
}
```

To register your custom tag helper you need add to `_ViewImports.cshtml`:

```
@addTagHelper *, [AssemblyName]
```

Then you can use it:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="CurrentThread.ThreadId" asp-short-name="true"/>
```

**Note:** As @Stephen Muecke noted the default model binding will not work. You may need to create a custom model binder or use other techniques to retrieve model values from the request